# Shell script to compare directories recursively

Tags: bash, shell, diff

I have a file server backup on an external hard drive a few months old for a file server that went down since then.  Most of the data was recovered onto a temporary file server thats been in use since then but there are some inconsistencies.

I am going to mount the external and rsync it with the current data to it but first I need to establish files that have gotten updated on the newer copy.

I can do diff -r -q /old/ /new/ to obtain this, I am trying to get better at scripting so I am trying to write something that will rename the old file to filename.old whenever diff returns a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after checking, I wasn't able to find an option in `diff` to only output the filename differences so we'll just work with what diff outputs.

If `diff` finds files that differ, the output is something like this:

```
Files old/file and new/file differ
```

Since all your bash script would be doing is renaming the changed file from the old directory, we want to extract `old/file` from this output. Let's start by only displaying lines like `Files...differ` (as other lines may be produced):

```
diff -rq old/ new/ | grep "^Files.*differ$"
```

Now you'll only get lines like the one shown before. Next step is getting the filename. You can do this with `awk` by adding something like `awk '{print $2}'` as another pipe but if the filename itself contains spaces, awk will break up that as two separate strings. We'll use sed instead:

```
diff -rq old/ new/ | grep "^Files.*differ$" | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ$/\1/'
```

Now this will produce a list of files that have changed in the old directory. Using a simple for loop, you can now rename each of the files:

```
for old_file in `diff -rq old/ new/ | grep "^Files.*differ$" | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ$/\1/'`
do
   mv $old_file $old_file.old
done
```

And that's it!

edit: actually, that's not all. This loop still fails on files with spaces so let's muck with it a bit. `for` will try to produce a list separated by a space by default. Let's change this to use newlines instead:

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
# The extra space after is crucial
IFS=\

for old_file in `diff -rq old/ new/ | grep "^Files.*differ$" | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ$/\1/'`
do
   mv $old_file $old_file.old
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

This temporarily replaces bash's default separator (`$IFS`) to a newline and puts it back after it's done with the loop so you don't split by space.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a way to work with the output using some simple regex, I'm just still getting used to piping commands.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a program `dircmp` lurking around systems.  If you have it, use it.

If you don't have and can't find it, then I have a version of it with minor extensions that you can use (see my profile for contact information).

Example output:

```
Files in ifxchkpath-4.12 only and in ifxchkpath-5.15 only

./Makefile                        ./absname.1
./program.mk                      ./absname.c
                                  ./chk.servers.sh
                                  ./chunklist.sh
                                  ./clnpath.c
                                  ./clnpath.h
                                  ./dirname.c
                                  ./enable.uids.sh
                                  ./errhelp.c
[...]
                                  ./lpt.pl
                                  ./makefile
                                  ./nvstrcpy.c
                                  ./realpath.c
                                  ./realpathtest.sh
                                  ./stderr.c
                                  ./stderr.h
                                  ./symlinks.tgz
                                  ./testids.mk
                                  ./test.linkpath.pl
                                  ./test.lpt.sh
                                  ./test.onsecurity.sh
                                  ./tokenise.c

Comparison of files in ifxchkpath-4.12 and ifxchkpath-5.15

directory           .
different           ./chk.ifxchkpath.sh
different           ./ifxchkpath.c
same                ./test.ifxchkpath.pl
```